# CheckBox in List

Tags: checkbox, sencha-touch-2

Is there a way to add checkboxes within the List's Item Template?

I've tried the following, which of course does not work:

```
{
            xtype: 'list',
            height: '100%',
            itemId: 'checkList',
            itemTpl: [
                '<div class="line">',
                '    <div class="label">',
                '        {text}',
                '    </div>',
                '    <input name="checkBox1" class="x-input-el x-input-checkbox" type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />',
                '    <div class="x-field-mask">',
                '        ::after',
                '    </div>',
                '    <input name="checkBox2" class="x-input-el x-input-checkbox" type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />',
                '    <div class="x-field-mask">',
                '        ::after',
                '    </div>'
            ],
            store: 'myStore'
},
```

I got the code reference by inspecting a checkbox element, but I assume that I have to render it completely different for it to work.

I have tried to search, but cannot find a way to do this.

Also if there is a way to disable the checkboxes, so they're read-only, considering I can't really call `disable()` for the checkboxes, if they're added in the item template or can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Use custom html in a template and register for events directly on DOM elements. This could perform better and is more customizable but has some downsides:

You will have to use http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.DomQuery to select your DOM elements and add behaviour to it. A good point to do that is on the store `load` method. It will be also your responsibility to unbind handlers if list items are going to be removed/added later. This solution could be impossible to implement if you want to use a Sencha Touch infinite list.

2) Use [Ext.dataView](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView) and [Ext.dataview.component.DataItem](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dataview.component.DataItem). That allows you to use the components of your choice in a DataView. You should implement something like this:

```
// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! MODEL

Ext.define('TestModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [{
            name: 'val1'
        }, {
            name: 'val2'
        }, {
            name: 'val3'
        }]
    }
});

// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! STORE

Ext.define('TestStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        data: [{
            val1: 'A Button',
            val2: 'with text',
            val3: true
        }, {
            val1: 'The Button',
            val2: 'more text',
            val3: false
        }, {
            val1: 'My Button',
            val2: 'My Text',
            val3: true
        }],
        model: 'TestModel',
        storeId: 'TestStore'
    }
});

// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! DATA ITEM

Ext.define('MyDataItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem',
    alias: 'widget.mydataitem',
    config: {
        padding: 10,
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        defaults: {
            margin: 5
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Val1'
        }, {
            xtype: 'component',
            flex: 1,
            html: 'val2',
            itemId: 'textCmp'
        }, {
            xtype: 'checkboxfield',
            flex: 1,
            name : 'val3',
            label: 'val3',
            value: 'val3',
            checked: 'val3'
        }]
    },
    updateRecord: function(record) {
        var me = this;

        me.down('button').setText(record.get('val1'));
        me.down('#textCmp').setHtml(record.get('val2'));
        me.down('checkboxfield').setChecked(record.get('val3'));

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! DATA VIEW

Ext.define('MyDataView', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
    config: {
        defaultType: 'mydataitem',
        useComponents: true
    }
});

// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! RUN

Ext.create('MyDataView', {
    fullscreen: true,
    store: Ext.create('TestStore')
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll look into using the data view! :)

Comment: After developing Sencha Touch apps for 2 years, I eventually always ended up with using option 1. Option 2 makes you write a lot of code, and it's not so easy to understand, I think you will have to struggle to get it working the first time. But it's good for you to try both and figure out by yourself which one is best for you.

Comment: Well I kinda have to go with the second option, because it's not for personal work, so I have to follow the structure of the existing project

Comment: There's one issue I can't seem to figure out. I get this error `Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.Container#setDefaultType] Invalid defaultType of: 'alias_of_dataitem_is_here', must be a valid component xtype` It seems like it can't find my data item component, although the alias matches the defaultType

Comment: Thinking of it choice one might be better, so if you could wrap up an example how I could ex. call a function inside a controller or how could I call the controls inside it from a controller?

Comment: You will have to use http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.DomQuery to select your DOM elements and add behaviour to it. A good point to do that is on the store `load` method. It will be also your responsibility to unbind handlers if list items are going to be removed/added later. This solution could be impossible to implement if you want to use a Sencha Touch infinite list.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to go with option two first, and when you will be more familiar with the framework, try option one.

Comment: Okay I will see what I can get out of this, but for now this actual task is put to the side :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87870/discussion-between-andrea-casaccia-and-bauss).